# Unittest discovery not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following project ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/UnittestDiscovery)):

[image]

Here's `test_some_unit.py`:

```py
from ..util.foo import run_foo


def test_some_unit():
    run_foo()
    print("Unit test")
```

Running discovery for `test.unit` produces 0 tests:

```
python -m unittest discover test.unit

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why?

Comment: `unittest` requires tests to be methods of classes (which inherit from `unittest.TestCase`). Unlike `pytest`, it doesn't support tests as module-level functions. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code

Comment: Thanks! If you make that into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test cases are module-level functions. `pytest` supports test cases written in that way, but `unittest` doesn't. In `unittest`, test cases are methods of test classes (which inherit from `unittest.TestCase`). (Reference: ["Organizing test code" in module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code)).

So you would need to reorganize your tests into this style for them to be discovered.

Comment: This answer solves my problem, thanks! However, I believe your last paragraph is not quite correct. You are right that namespace packages are no longer supported by `unittest`, but my `test.unit` package is not a namespace package, it is a regular package because it contains an `__init__.py` file. The link you gave says that regular packages (those with `__init__.py`) *are* supported.

Comment: Aha, you're quite right on that. Thanks for the clarification!